# Can ls() have a pattern > 1?

Tags: r

Say I have 10 `data.frame`s that contain dates in their names from `01-01-00` to `10-01-00` with other letters and symbols added to the end in the format `ddmmyy`

**E.g.** `010100/sgh/d_3`and `020100/aff/d_1`

If I wanted to create a vector of the above `data.frame`, is there a way to select them without writing them out individually?

I tried creating a vector of a sequence of dates and putting this in to `pattern =` but came up with error (code below):

```
Dates <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2000-01-02"),1)
Dates <- format(Dates,"%d%m%y")
ls(pattern=Dates)

In grep(pattern, all.names, value = TRUE) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I'm assuming that pattern can only be one value?

Comment: @LyzandeR no it wont. it will match things with the word "Dates" in the name.

Comment: Have a look at `stri_detect` from package `stringi`. I love this package, it offers all regex based operations with a coherent syntax!

Comment: Actually `stri_subset` applied on `ls()` should do what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a pattern that matches any of the date strings you want. One way is to join all the strings up with `|` characters:

```
> Dates <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2000-01-10"),1)
> Dates
 [1] "2000-01-01" "2000-01-02" "2000-01-03" "2000-01-04" "2000-01-05"
 [6] "2000-01-06" "2000-01-07" "2000-01-08" "2000-01-09" "2000-01-10"
> D2 = paste(Dates,collapse="|")
> D2
[1] "2000-01-01|2000-01-02|2000-01-03|2000-01-04|2000-01-05|2000-01-06|2000-01-07|2000-01-08|2000-01-09|2000-01-10"
```

Now I have a workspace with various bits and pieces in:

```
> ls()
 [1] "d"              "d010100foo"     "d010110bar"     "D2"            
 [5] "d2000-01-01bar" "d2000-01-10bar" "d2000-02-10foo" "Dates"         
 [9] "dorig"          "j"              "p"              "x"             
[13] "y"              "z"
```

But if I use that pattern I get the ones that match the dates:

```
> ls(pattern=D2)
[1] "d2000-01-01bar" "d2000-01-10bar"
```

This could get unwieldy if you had lots of things to match, but that that point you can probably write a simpler regexp to match all the things - something like `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}` (untested) which should match any four digit, dash, two digit, dash, two digit sequence.

Adjust the pattern to match your date format. The format you have used is not recommended: https://xkcd.com/1179/